# Accordion Next Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried searching for what I am trying to accomplish, however I have not found what I am looking for.

I am looking to create a Next and Previous button inside the content of the Spry Accordion provided with Dreamweaver CS6. I have searched the SpryAccordion.js and found this code below:

```
Spry.Widget.Accordion.prototype.openNextPanel = function()
{
    return this.openPanel(this.getCurrentPanelIndex() + 1);
};

Spry.Widget.Accordion.prototype.openPreviousPanel = function()
{
    return this.openPanel(this.getCurrentPanelIndex() - 1);
};
```

So I attempted to do this with "#acc-step-1-next" being my "Next" button in Panel 1.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#acc-step-1-next").click(function(){
        Spry.Widget.Accordion.prototype.openNextPanel = function(){
            return ('#Accordian1').openPanel(this.getCurrentPanelIndex() + 1);
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

I was wondering if doing it this way might make it easy! How would I go about applying this? Would this work or not?

Also, with the "Next" button, could I just make it ".acc-step-next" and use it universally, instead of individually assigning new ID's?

EDIT:
Sorry, yes I read your answer incorrectly. I have tried searching for the init property, however have had no success.

This is what starts in the Accordion JS file:

```
(function() { // BeginSpryComponent

if (typeof Spry == "undefined") window.Spry = {}; if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.Widget.Accordion = function(element, opts)
{
this.element = this.getElement(element);
this.defaultPanel = 0;
this.hoverClass = "AccordionPanelTabHover";
this.openClass = "AccordionPanelOpen";
this.closedClass = "AccordionPanelClosed";
this.focusedClass = "AccordionFocused";
this.enableAnimation = true;
this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
this.currentPanel = null;
this.animator = null;
this.hasFocus = null;

this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.Accordion.KEY_UP;
this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.Accordion.KEY_DOWN;

this.useFixedPanelHeights = false;
this.fixedPanelHeight = 0;

Spry.Widget.Accordion.setOptions(this, opts, true);

if (this.element)
    this.attachBehaviors();
};
```

Which I added this after, but still no luck:

```
var acc_next = document.getElementById("acc-step-next");
var acc_prev = document.getElementById("acc-step-prev");

$("acc_next").click(function(){
    accordion.openNextPanel();
});
$("acc_prev").click(function() {
    accordion.openPreviousPanel();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Spry.Widget.Accordion, but I would try something like the following.

Search for the code, where your accordion is initialized, it should look something like that:

```
var accordion = new Spry.Widget.Accordion("Accordian1",{});
```

And add this just below:

```
$(".acc-step-next").click(function(){
    accordion.openNextPanel();
});
```

Together it could look something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accordion = new Spry.Widget.Accordion("Accordian1",{});

    // Add a click handler to all buttons with the class 'acc-step-next' (yes you can do that)
    $(".acc-step-next").click(function(){
        // when the button is clicked, call the openNextPanel method of the accordion instance we saved above
        accordion.openNextPanel();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem is that it creates a new Accordion. I already have one called "#Accordion1" that I would like to make open. How would I do that?

Comment: Thats why I said you should search for the code where your accordion is initialized and add the click handler below. Or you find another way to get the accordion instance, then you can place the code wherever you want. But I don't know how Spry.Widget.Accordion works, so I don't know how you can get the instance somewhere else.